# Angular Firebase not redirecting to dashboard after register / signup

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, redirect

I replaced this code (which is my signup.component.ts):

```
private signupSuccess(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/authentication/login');
}
```

with this:

```
private signupSuccess(){
this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');

}
```

this is what my isloggedin looks like (authentication.guard.ts):

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn)
      return true
    else
      return this.router.parseUrl("/dashboard");
  }
```

but even after successfully registering/signing up, it is only stuck on the register page... [image: Here]

And also, how do I pass this parameter `src=signup` and where?

EDIT: The problem seems to be on the auth guard side with this line

```
return this.router.parseUrl("/dashboard");
```

Comment: Router.navigateByUrl  accepts string in its argument and the navigation should be absolute and start with a /:

private signupSuccess() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard;src=signup');
}

Comment: Hello @Gopal, thank you for replying! but what do you mean by absolute and it should start with the line of code you sent...

I wrote what you sent and I still get stuck on the successfully registered prompt